# how to display information of a selected line in inputs?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

Here is my problem I want when I click on a button that is in a row of an html array, the information of the select line is displayed in inputs and it is not editable.

Here is my interface to better understand:

[Home locataire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqcU8.png)

I want that when I click on reserve the following modal is displayed, and the modal stock inputs the information of the selected line, here is my modal:

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us12R.png)

the problem is that I really do not know how to do that with code.

here is the code of my page jsp if need:

```
    <%@page import="controller.Cnx"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<%

Connection c=Cnx.getcnx();
Statement st=c.createStatement();
ResultSet re=st.executeQuery("select * from place");
Statement st2=c.createStatement();
ResultSet re2=st2.executeQuery("select * from local");
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Interface locataire</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Sufee Admin - HTML5 Admin Template">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/themify-icons/css/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/selectFX/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Css_acceuil_locataire.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3fd0d5f24.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default" style="flex-flow:column wrap;">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gestion parkings</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand hidden" href="./"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="main-menu" class="main-menu collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-right: 80px;"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" style="margin-right: 10px;" selected></i>Réservation</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-right: 80px;"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" style="margin-right: 10px;" selected></i>Liste réservation</a>

                    </li>



                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </aside>



    <nav class="navbar" style="height:70px;" id='nav-proprietaire'>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="Page_de_cnx" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding-left: 1430px; text-transform: uppercase"> <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>Déconnection</a>

                    </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


        <label id="label1">Liste des places disponibles avec leurs emplacements :</label>

        <table class="table table-hover" style="margin-top: 20px;" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-active">
      <th scope="col">Nom local</th>
      <th scope="col">Numéro place</th>
      <th scope="col">Prix par heure</th>
      <th scope="col">Taille</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>


    </tr>
     </thead>
     <%while(re.next()){%> 
     <tr>

            <th scope="row"><%=re.getObject(2)%></th>
            <td><%=re.getObject(3)%></td>
            <td><%=re.getObject(4)%></td>
            <td>><%=re.getObject(5)%></td>
            <td>><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservation" onclick="afficher()"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>Réserver</a></td>
     </tr>


      <%}%>

  <tbody>





  </tbody>

</table>
   <div class="modal" id="reservation">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Information</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form method="POST" action='Place_locaux'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Nom du local approprié à la place :</label>
                <select class="browser-default custom-select" placeheader="Search here.." name="nom_local" required disabled>


                        <%while(re2.next()){%>
                        <option><%=re2.getObject(2)%></option>
                        <%}%>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Numéro place :</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numeroplace"  name="numeroplace" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Prix par heure:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prixplace" placeholder="Entrer le prix de la place" name="prixplace" required>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Taille de la place :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tailleplace" placeholder="Entrer la taille de la place" name="tailleplace" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Votre Cin :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cinlocataire" placeholder="Entrer votre cin" name="cinlocataire" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Heure début de la réservation :</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="heure_debut" placeholder="Entrer l'heure de début" name="heure_debut" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='labelproprietaire'>Heure fin de la réservation :</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="heure_fin" placeholder="Entrer l'heure de fin" name="heure_fin" required>

            </div>






        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">

         <div id='divbtnaddplace'>      
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id='btnreserver' style='vertical-align: 0; margin-right: 260px;' name='action' value='reserver'>Reserver</button>


           </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>     


        <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


    <script src="vendors/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript code :

```
<script>

    var table= document.getElementById('table1');

    for(int i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
        function afficher(){
         document.getElementById('nom_local').value=this.cells[0].innerHtml;
         document.getElementById('numeroplace').value=this.cells[1].innerHtml;
         document.getElementById('prixplace').value=this.cells[2].innerHtml;
         document.getElementById('tailleplace').value=this.cells[3].innerHtml;
        }
    }
</script>
```

help me please !

Comment: Have you tried attaching an event handler to each of your Reserve buttons? You could then grab the contents of that specific row and populate your modal's fields. What you're doing now would just populate your modal with the last rows data.

Comment: yes i did onclick="afficher()" you can show my jsp code but is doesn't work

Comment: I don't see a click event handler anywhere in your code. Can you point out where in your code you're attaching your event handler? Your function afficher is just being executed in a loop and I don't see it referenced anywhere else.

Comment: it is in the button of the table I forgot to mention it at the beginning but I just add it now

Comment: <td>><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservation" name="reservermodal" onclick="afficher()" ><i class="fas fa-plus" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>Réserver</a></td>

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your reserve button and bind an on click event handler to your button. From there, you can pull the data from that row and populate your modal's fields. Here's an example using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.reserve').on('click', function(e) {
        var rowData = $(this).parent().parent().children();
        $('#nom_local').val($(rowData).eq(0).text());
        $('#numeroplace').val($(rowData).eq(1).text());
        $('#prixplace').val($(rowData).eq(2).text());
        $('#tailleplace').val($(rowData).eq(3).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet will help you out

```js
jQuery(document).ready(($) => {

    let orderedList = $('<ol></ol>');

    jQuery.fx.interval = 7;

    $('table').on({
        mouseover: (e) => {
            if (e.target.parentNode.nodeName !== 'BODY') {
                if (!$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(e.target.parentNode).attr('class', 'over');
                }
            }
        },
        mouseout: (e) => {
            if (!$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(e.target.parentNode).attr('class', 'out');
            }
        },
        click: (e) => {
            if ($(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(e.target.parentNode).attr('class', 'out');
                let children = orderedList.first().children();
                $(children).each((index, c) => {
                    if (c.textContent == e.target.parentNode.textContent) {
                        let element = c;
                        $(element).animate(
                            {
                                opacity: 0
                            }, 1000, () => {
                                $(element).remove();
                                if($(orderedList).children().length == 0) {
                                    $(orderedList).hide('slow');
                                }
                            });

                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(e.target.parentNode).attr('class', 'selected');
                if (orderedList.children().length === 0) {
                    orderedList.text('You have chosen:')
                        .hide()
                        .appendTo(document.body)
                        .show('slow');
                }
                let listItem = $('<li></li>');
                listItem.text(e.target.parentNode.textContent)
                    .hide();
                orderedList.append(listItem);
                listItem.show('slow');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.over {
    background-color: aqua;
}

.out {
    background-color: white;
}

.selected {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

li.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            First header
        </th>
        <th>
            Second header
        </th>
        <th>
            Third header
        </th>
        <th>
            Fourth header
        </th>
        <th>
            Fifth header
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            First Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            Second Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            Third Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            Fourth Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            Fifth Cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            1 Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            2 Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            3 Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            4 Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            5 Cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            F Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            S Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            T Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            F Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            F Cell
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script async src="test.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.